# How to reorder the XML unmarshalling

Tags: jaxb

I need to know if we can unmarshal the object to the order we want.

ex: we have three classes A, B and C. order of unmarshalling is also in the same order.

As my concepts are not that clear but as far as I know the unmarshalling happens in the order in which it was marshaled.

As there is a development constrains I cannot change the order of marshalling objects. so is there a way to change the order to unmarshal B's objects first before A's objects.

I am using JAXB api's.

Thanks,
Suvidh

Answer (score 0):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations do not require that the elements in the XML document strictly match the order defined in the XML schema.  If you wish to enforce an order then you can set an instance of `javax.xml.validation.Schema` on the `Unmarshaller`.

Comment: I am not finding a proper examples.. please elaborate with an example.

Comment: @user1502919 - Could you update your question with more details on what you are looking for?